# Doubly linked list in Rust using raw pointers

Tags: beginner, linked-list, rust

I am practicing Rust by writing doubly linked list using raw pointers, `Box<node>` to allocate data on heap, `Box::from_raw` to free data from heap. I feel it very silly to use a lot of unsafe blocks.

```
struct node<T> {
    value: T,
    prev: *mut node<T>,
    next: *mut node<T>
}
impl<T> Drop for node<T> {
    fn drop(self: &mut Self) {
        println!("Dropping anode");
    }
}
impl<T> node<T> {
    fn new(value: T, prev: *mut node<T>, next: *mut node<T>) -> Self {
        return Self{value: value, prev: prev, next: next};
    }
}

struct list<T> {
    root: *mut node<T>
}
impl<T> Drop for list<T> {
    fn drop(self: &mut Self) {
        let mut this: *mut node<T> = self.root;
        let mut drop: *mut node<T> = std::ptr::null_mut();
        while this != std::ptr::null_mut() {
            drop = this;
            unsafe {this = (*this).next;}
            unsafe {let anode = Box::from_raw(drop);}
        }
    }
}

impl std::fmt::Display for list<f64> {
    fn fmt(self: &Self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "[");
        let mut this: *mut node<f64> = self.root;
        while this != std::ptr::null_mut() {
            unsafe {write!(f, "{} ", (*this).value);}
            unsafe {this = (*this).next;}
        }
        write!(f, "]");
        return Ok(());
    }
}

impl<T> list<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let p : *mut node<T> = std::ptr::null_mut();
        return Self {root: p};
    }
    fn len(self: &Self) -> i32 {
        let mut len: i32 = 0;
        let mut this: *mut node<T> = self.root;
        while this != std::ptr::null_mut()
        {
            len += 1;
            unsafe {
                this = (*this).next;
            }
        }
        return len;
    }
    fn getnode(self: &Self, mut i: i32) -> *mut node<T> {
        let mut this: *mut node<T> = self.root;
        let mut next: *mut node<T> = std::ptr::null_mut();
        while i > 0 {
            unsafe {
                next = (*this).next;
            }
            if next == std::ptr::null_mut() {
                return std::ptr::null_mut();
            } else {
                i -= 1;
                this = next;
            }
        }
        return this;

    }
    fn insert(mut self: &mut Self, mut i: i32, value: T) {
        let mut next: *mut node<T> = self.getnode(i);
        let mut prev: *mut node<T> = std::ptr::null_mut();

        if i != 0 {
            if next == std::ptr::null_mut() {
                let lastindex: i32 = self.len() - 1;
                prev = self.getnode(lastindex);
            } else {
                unsafe {prev = (*next).prev;}
            }
        }
        let mut anode: Box<node<T>> = Box::new(node::new(value, prev, next));
        let mut this = Box::into_raw(anode);

        if i == 0 {
            self.root = this;
        }

        if next != std::ptr::null_mut() {
            unsafe {(*next).prev = this;}
        }
        if prev != std::ptr::null_mut() {
            unsafe {(*prev).next = this;}
        }
    }
    fn erase(mut self: &mut Self, mut i: i32) {
        let mut this: *mut node<T> = self.getnode(i);
        if this == std::ptr::null_mut() {return;}
        let mut prev: *mut node<T> = std::ptr::null_mut();
        let mut next: *mut node<T> = std::ptr::null_mut();
        unsafe {
            prev = (*this).prev;
            next = (*this).next;
        }
        if prev != std::ptr::null_mut() {
            unsafe {(*prev).next = next;}
        }
        if next != std::ptr::null_mut() {
            unsafe {(*next).prev = prev;}
        }
        if i == 0 {
            self.root = next;
        }

        unsafe {let anode: Box<node<T>> = Box::from_raw(this);}
    }
    fn getvalue(self: Self, mut i: i32) -> &'static T {
        let this: *mut node<T> = self.getnode(i);
        unsafe {
            return &(*this).value;
        }
    }
}




pub fn main() {
    let mut l: list<f64> = list::new();

    l.insert(0, 3.0);
    println!("{}", l);
    l.insert(0, 4.0);
    println!("{}", l);
    l.insert(1, 1.0);
    println!("{}", l);
    l.insert(2, 6.0);
    println!("{}", l);
    l.insert(2, 5.4);
    println!("{}", l);
    l.insert(5, 3.3);
    println!("{}", l);

    l.erase(3);
    println!("{}", l);
    l.erase(4);
    println!("{}", l);
    l.erase(0);
    println!("{}", l);
}
```

Comment: Hi, please use a title that reflect what your code does, not what you want from the review :)

Comment: You may want to read through https://github.com/rust-unofficial/too-many-lists, which builds quite a few linked lists in Rust.

Answer (score 2):

Note: I will not consider the question whether raw pointers are the best approach to building a linked list, but you could look at smart pointers for alternatives.

## Compiler warnings

Running this code gives 21 warnings and suggestions what to change. Many of them refer to unused variables or unnecessary usages of `mut`.
Listen to them and fix them:

- `node`, `list` should be `Node`, `List`
- remove unnecessary `mut`
- use `?` after the `write!` calls to return any possible errors
- do not initialize values to null and overwrite them then, just use

```rust
let mut variable_name;
```

instead of

```rust
let mut variable_name: *mut node<T> = std::ptr::null_mut();
```

## Style

Use `cargo clippy` to find many more issues, such as:

- `self: &Self` -> `&self`, `self: &mut Self` -> `&mut self`
- shorthand initialization:

```rust
Self {
    value: value,
    prev: prev,
    next: next,
}
```

can be just

```rust
Self {
    value,
    prev,
    next,
}
```

- unneeded `return` at the end of a function
- use `ptr.is_null()` instead of `ptr == std::ptr::null_mut()`

## Debugging artifact

This implementation seems to be a remaining piece of debugging that shouldn't be kept in production:

```rust
impl<T> Drop for Node<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Dropping anode");
    }
}
```

## More flexible `Display` for `List`

Right now, you only implement it for `List<f64>`, but you can implement it for any type that implements `Display`:

```rust
use std::fmt;

impl<T: fmt::Display> fmt::Display for List<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "[")?;
        let mut this = self.root;
        while !this.is_null() {
            unsafe {
                write!(f, "{} ", (*this).value)?;
            }
            unsafe {
                this = (*this).next;
            }
        }
        write!(f, "]")?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

## Likely typo

`List::getvalue` should probably take `&self` instead of `self` as an argument to avoid consuming the entire list.

## Final code

I have also used `cargo fmt` to format the code according to the rust style guidelines.

```rust
use std::fmt;

struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    prev: *mut Node<T>,
    next: *mut Node<T>,
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn new(value: T, prev: *mut Node<T>, next: *mut Node<T>) -> Self {
        Self { value, prev, next }
    }
}

struct List<T> {
    root: *mut Node<T>,
}

impl<T> Drop for List<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let mut this = self.root;
        while !this.is_null() {
            let dropped = this;
            unsafe {
                this = (*this).next;
            }
            unsafe {
                drop(Box::from_raw(dropped));
            }
        }
    }
}

impl<T: fmt::Display> fmt::Display for List<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "[")?;
        let mut this = self.root;
        while !this.is_null() {
            unsafe {
                write!(f, "{} ", (*this).value)?;
            }
            unsafe {
                this = (*this).next;
            }
        }
        write!(f, "]")?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

impl<T> List<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            root: std::ptr::null_mut(),
        }
    }

    fn len(&self) -> i32 {
        let mut len = 0;
        let mut this = self.root;
        while !this.is_null() {
            len += 1;
            unsafe {
                this = (*this).next;
            }
        }
        len
    }

    fn getnode(&self, mut i: i32) -> *mut Node<T> {
        let mut this = self.root;
        let mut next;
        while i > 0 {
            unsafe {
                next = (*this).next;
            }
            if next.is_null() {
                return std::ptr::null_mut();
            } else {
                i -= 1;
                this = next;
            }
        }
        this
    }

    fn insert(&mut self, i: i32, value: T) {
        let next = self.getnode(i);
        let mut prev = std::ptr::null_mut();

        if i != 0 {
            if next.is_null() {
                let lastindex = self.len() - 1;
                prev = self.getnode(lastindex);
            } else {
                unsafe {
                    prev = (*next).prev;
                }
            }
        }
        let anode = Box::new(Node::new(value, prev, next));
        let this = Box::into_raw(anode);

        if i == 0 {
            self.root = this;
        }

        if !next.is_null() {
            unsafe {
                (*next).prev = this;
            }
        }
        if !prev.is_null() {
            unsafe {
                (*prev).next = this;
            }
        }
    }

    fn erase(&mut self, i: i32) {
        let this = self.getnode(i);
        if this.is_null() {
            return;
        }
        let prev;
        let next;
        unsafe {
            prev = (*this).prev;
            next = (*this).next;
        }
        if !prev.is_null() {
            unsafe {
                (*prev).next = next;
            }
        }
        if !next.is_null() {
            unsafe {
                (*next).prev = prev;
            }
        }
        if i == 0 {
            self.root = next;
        }

        unsafe {
            drop(Box::from_raw(this));
        }
    }

    fn getvalue(&self, i: i32) -> &'static T {
        let this = self.getnode(i);
        unsafe { &(*this).value }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let mut l = List::new();

    l.insert(0, 3.0);
    println!("{}", l);
    l.insert(0, 4.0);
    println!("{}", l);
    l.insert(1, 1.0);
    println!("{}", l);
    l.insert(2, 6.0);
    println!("{}", l);
    l.insert(2, 5.4);
    println!("{}", l);
    l.insert(5, 3.3);
    println!("{}", l);

    l.erase(3);
    println!("{}", l);
    l.erase(4);
    println!("{}", l);
    l.erase(0);
    println!("{}", l);
}
```